# get, match and resources in routes.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to Rails. I found it very strange when I use the resources in routes.rb, after I redirect the page to controller/index, it render the controller/show .

I know `GET controller/action` is same as `match "controller/action", :to => "controller/action"`

I think the strange thing happens to me about the redirect, is similar to the GET and Match.

so I wonder what exactly the resources mean, can I use some simple match do the same thing?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`resources` is a shortcut for generating seven routes needed for a [REST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/REST) interface.

`resources :widgets` is equivalent to writing

```
get    "widgets"          => "widgets#index",   :as => 'widgets'
get    "widgets/:id"      => "widgets#show",    :as => 'widget'
get    "widgets/new"      => "widgets#new",     :as => 'new_widget'
post   "widgets"          => "widgets#create",  :as => 'widgets'
get    "widgets/:id/edit" => "widgets#edit",    :as => 'edit_widget'
patch  "widgets/:id"      => "widgets#update",  :as => 'widget'
put    "widgets/:id"      => "widgets#update",  :as => 'widget'
delete "widgets/:id"      => "widgets#destroy", :as => 'widget'
```

it just saves you the trouble.

By the way, `get` is not exactly the same as `match`. `get`, `post`, `put` and `delete` are shortcuts for limiting the route to a single HTTP verb. The two route definitions below are equivalent.

```
match 'foo' => 'controller#action', :method => :get
get   'foo' => 'controller#action'
```

Comment: Wow, That's the exactly information I want, Thanks edgerunner

Comment: Recent Rails also includes a `patch` route, which is the same as the `put` one.